# flutter_reactive_ble not able to connect with release build (Flutter version 3.3.4)

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter_reactive_ble package for bluetooth connections, upon upgrading to the latest Flutter version (3.3.4), I am connecting as expected when debugging however the release build does not connect (works on both builds with Flutter 3.0.5).

Hoping someone may have encountered this with suggestions/solution.

Comment: Wat device? you using IOS/Android? or both in release?

Comment: I occurs on both platforms.

Comment: On what pair did you tried ? arduino? or a device which handle hm10?>

Comment: We are using the Infineon CYW89373 module which is BT 5.0 compliant.

Comment: Did you solve this? I get the same issue

Comment: @rednaxela No, we do not have any solution yet.  Have not been able to take a deep dive into it yet.  Kind of hoping additional Flutter versions would fix, but last checked 3.3.6 which did not (I see it is up to 3.3.8, however have not tested that yet).  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I answered with what worked for me. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with Flutter 3.7.9 and iOS 16.3.1 on an iPad (8th generation) when executing either `flutter run --release` or `flutter run --profile`.

https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/issues/457 suggests the problem may be a race condition where the UI Widgets are built before the BLE platform initializes. My application was scanning for BLE devices as soon as it launched, and several widgets on the home screen consumed the stream.

I solved my problem by calling `scanForDevices()` followed by a `Future.delayed()` call before building the first widgets that consumed the `scanForDevices()` stream. [This related issue](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/issues/147#issuecomment-1329862732) suggests that waiting for `BleStatus.ready` before scanning may solve, but I have not tested that as it did not work for my use case.

Answer (score -1):

So here is the fix!

Turns out it was in the [FAQ](https://github.com/ekasetiawans/flutter_background_service/tree/master/packages/flutter_background_service#service-not-running-in-release-mode)  of the flutter_background_service package also being used by us (this answer is specific for use with this package).

The dart compiler for release mode builds will do tree shaking (removal of dead code) and minifying (shortening variable and method names, removing white space and comments, etc) to shrink the size of the app. Both of these do not happen in debug mode. People are assuming that in Dart 2.18 (which came with Flutter 3.3) the tree shaking and/or minifying was updated. onStart(...) was being removed/shrunk during tree shaking / minifying and therefore the native code in the FlutterBackgroundService package couldn't find it, causing the background service to never start up. @pragma('vm:entry-point') makes it so that onStart(...) isn't removed or shortened during those size optimizations.

I am still not certain whether the issue was tree shaking or minifying. My google searches make it lean towards tree shaking, however, the app worked on profile mode builds which perform tree shaking but not minifying, which makes me lean towards minifying. I don't think it really matters if we know or not.

Some documentation for @pragma('vm:entry-point'): https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/runtime/docs/compiler/aot/entry_point_pragma.md

Easy to read post about tree shaking and minification: http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/01/minification-is-not-enough-you-need.html

In-depth info about tree shaking: https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/the-tree-shaking-mechanism-in-flutter_597737